# agregar un item o celda teniendo un array, en un collectionView

Tags: array, swift3, uicollectionview

saludos a todos! espero que alguien pueda resolver mi problema, tengo mi CollectionView, y en el puse un sampleObject, que contiene una imagen y un label y una función para agregar estos ejemplos, este devuelve un array y lo coloco en mi colección: y cuando quiero añadir un objeto nuevo a dicha colección lo hago desde otro ViewController, pero no me agrega nada a la colección no se que este haciendo mal soy nuevo en esto, alguien menciono que depende como tenga instanciada la clase en donde se encuentra el objeto collectionView, y que esta se tiene que inicializar,pero no he encontrado nada les pongo mi código:

este es mi modelo de objeto:

```
   class SampleObjects: NSObject {

      var image: String?
      var name: String?

      init(name: String, image: String) {
          self.image = name
          self.name = image
          super.init()
   }

// funcion para crear los ejemplos de objetos
   static func sampleNewObject() -> [SampleObjects] {

    var objectos = [SampleObjetc]()

    let objetoUno = SampleObjects(name: "nombre", Image: "miImagen")
    objetos.append(objetoUno)

    return objetos

}
```

coloco la instancia del objeto en el viewController donde tengo mi collectionView:

```
  var misObjetos: [SampleObjects]?
```

tambien creo una instancia del objeto en el collectionViewCell para poder colocar los datos del SampleObject y aparezcan en la vista y los cuales se relacionan con las propiedades dentro del collectionViewCell:

```
   var objetosEnCollection: SampleObjetos? {
    didSet {
        if let name = propiedadEnCollection?.name {
            nameImage.text = name
        }
        if let imageName = propiedadCollection?.image {
            image.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
        }
    }
}
```

y lo coloco en la seccion en mi collectionView:

```
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if collectionView == miCollectionView {
        if let countObjetos = misObjetos?.count {
            return countObjetos
        }
        return 0
    }
```

y después en la celda de la colección:

```
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if collectionView == instrumentCarousel {
        let cell: miColleccionCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: carouselCellId, for: indexPath) as! miColleccionCell

        if let celda = misObjetos?[indexPath.item] {
           cell.misObjetos = celda
        }

        return cell
    }
```

tambien accedo a los datos del modelo para que pueda agregar la función y colóco en el ViewController donde esta mi collectionView:

```
 misObjetos = SampleObjects.sampleNewObject()
```

todo bien aqui me aparece en la celda bien si agrego mas objetos al array dentro de la función en SampleObjetc... y me aparece en el CollectionView...

el detalle es en este punto... estoy en otro viewController, y tengo un botón, en cual va agregar un objeto mas dentro del array para la celda del collectionView.. y hago lo siguiente...

instancio las clases para llamar la coleccion en donde va ir el nuevo objeto

```
 var misObjetos: [SampleObjects]?

 var miColeccion: miCollectionView?
       // no se si tenga que inicializar aqui esta declaración si es asi no se como hacerlo...
```

y en la función del botón hago lo siguiente:

```
   @objc func addTrack()  {


    let objetosCollection = ViewController.miCollectionView

    let new = SampleObjects.init(name: "nombre", image: "miImagen")

    do {
        misObjetos.append(new)

        let item = misObjetos.count + 1
        let insertOnCollection = IndexPath(item: item, section: 0)
        objetosCollection?.insertItems(at: [insertOnCollection])

    }

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

y corre la app, pero al querer agregar el objeto no coloca nada, quizá no es la manera de agregar un objeto a la colección, he estado buscando una solución y no he encontrado con nada, espero alguien pueda quitarme esta duda... utilizo Swift 4, saludos a todos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes un par de cosas que deberías cambiar.
Tu modelo de datos, lo tienes en un controlador (CollectionView) y debería ser ahí donde lo modifiques. Lo inicializas y le añades, consultas o le quitas elementos, pero no debes volver a crear un array con la nueva información y devolvérselo, porque eliminara todo lo anterior.
El envio del nuevo modelo que has creado en el ViewController hacia el CollectionView deberas hacerlo con un protocolo o usando un delegado. En el ViewController creas lo nuevo y lo pasas y ahí termina su función. El CollectionView deberia integrarlo al modelo existente y recargar la collectionView.

Fíjate en los nombres que te pongo, **C**ollectionView el controlador, collectionView es el collectionView de **C**ollectionView.

El modelo lo tienes creado como esta, no necesitas sampleNewObject()

En CollectionView defines una propiedad de tu modelo, no es necesario que sea opcional, lo creas vacío

```
var misObjetos: [SampleObjects] = []
```

El numberOfItemsInSection  ahora lo puedes simplificar, ya que sabes que misObjectos existe siempre y no tienes que asegurar si es nil o no. Si solo tienes una collectionView en el controlador también puedes evitar comprobar la collectionView. Entiendo que solo tiene una sección.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return misObjetos.count
```

}

En el cellForItemAt un poco de lo mismo, puedes evitar la comprobación de la collectionView y para obtener el elemento a mostrar no es necesario el opcional, te vale con cambiar el

```
let celda = misObjetos[indexPath.row]
```

Vamos con la creación de un nuevo elemento. Lo primero es saber como le va a pasar el ViewController la información a CollectionView. Como te decía o protocolo o delegado. Probaremos con delegado, así pues en ViewController tenemos que crear el delegado que apunta al controlador de tipo CollectionView. Defines la propiedad en ViewController

var delegate: CollectionView?

No tienes especificado como haces la transición a ViewController, imagino que tendrás un botón por alguna lado, pues le pones esto en el action (o como hagas)

```
let vc = ViewController()
vc.delegate = self
self.present(vc,animated: true, completion: nil)
```

En el ViewController tendrás lo que sea para insertar los datos que quieras de la forma que sea, el caso es que cuando tengas esa información tienes que crear un nuevo elemento para tu modelo de datos que lo crearas con su init que tienes ya creado

```
let nuevo = SampleObjects(name:"Yan", image:"foto")
```

y ahora se lo paso al delegado y como? pues he de crearme un metodo que reciba ese nuevo elemento así pues le voy a llamar nuevoElemento (si, soy muy original)
y se lo pasas de esta forma

```
self.delegate.nuevoElemento(item: nuevo)
//y cerramos ViewController, que ya ha hecho suficiente
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Ahora tenemos que implementar el nuevoElemento en el delegado, que es CollectionView, así que te creas un nuevo método en CollectionView

```
func nuevoElemento(item: SampleObjects) {
    //me han pasado el nuevo elemento, solo tengo que añadirlo a lo que ya tengo
    self.misObjetos.append(item)
    //recargo la collectionView
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Podría suceder que el collectionView.reloadData() no haga nada, a veces me ha pasado que el dato esta y no recarga, en ese caso en lugar de reloadData le dices a la collectionView que has insertado un nuevo elemento y ya se ocupara de hacer lo que sea, en ese caso habría que cambiar esto:

```
func nuevoElemento(item: SampleObjects) {
    //me han pasado el nuevo elemento, solo tengo que añadirlo a lo que ya tengo
    self.misObjetos.append(item)
    //le digo a la collectionView que inserte un nuevo elemento
    let ip = NSIndexPath(row: self.misObjectos.count - 1, section:0)
    self.collectionView.insertItemsAtIndexPaths([ip])
}
```

**Version con protocolo:**
Creamos un protocolo, lo puedes escribir donde te de la gana, yo suelo ponerlo en el controlador emisor, en este caso ViewController.

```
protocol CollectionViewProtocol {
    func nuevoElemento(item: SampleObjects)
}
```

Ahora tienes que tener una propiedad que sea del tipo protocolo, así que no usaeremos el delegado de antes y necesitas una propiedad que sea por ejemplo

```
var collectionControllerProtocol: CollectionViewProtocol?
```

cuando creamos el ViewController para mostrarlo, en lugar del delegare tenemos que pasar el protocolo

```
let vc = ViewController()
vc. collectionControllerProtocol = self
self.present(vc,animated: true, completion: nil)
```

En el ViewController, una vez que ya sabes el nombre y la imagen que quieres insertar, pues creas el elemento de la misma forma que antes y después ejecutas el método del protocolo en lugar del delegado

```
self.collectionControllerProtocol?.nuevoElemento(item: nuevo)
```

Ahora solo tienes que hacer que CollectionView implemente el protocolo.

```
extension CollectionView: CollectionViewProtocol {
func nuevoElemento(item: SampleObjects) {
 //la misma función que esta para el delegado
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias por responder @Spidvmp, todo lo sigo al pie de la letra, mi duda es cuando le pasas el elemento usando el método nuevoElemento(item: SampleObjects) ahi me marca que delegate no es miembro de nuevoElemento,      ... este código lo puse en el botón para agregar, ... el delegado lo coloco en donde tengo el collectionView? o en el viewController donde esta la función y el botón. para agregar el elemento? nuevamente muchas gracias!

Comment: ya vi que la función va en el Delegado en este caso CollectionView, y no en el viewController donde tengo el botón... hago todo al pie de la letra, pero me devuelve un nil, y no agrega nada lo voy estar analizando quizá hice algo mal, ya intente con insertAtItem y con reload data pero nada..

Comment: ya funciono Spidvmp mediante protocolos,.... una pequeña duda ..funcionaria de la misma manera teniendo dos collectionsViews en un ViewController?... y nuevamente  muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Si, pero entonces si que tendrías que hacer el if collectionView = en todos los métodos del delegado y datasource de collectionView para saber cuantos elementos hay en un collectionView o en el otro, que celda hay que pntar, etc

Comment: gracias nuevamente @Spidvmp, si lo hice como mencionas colocando el if, y hace todo correcto, ahora, por ejemplo, se le puede decir al viewController que hay otro protocolo aparte del que ya esta conectado? digamos que hay un OtroViewController... y tambien tiene Collectionsview, se agregan me imagino al protocolo existente las funciones como en el ViewController o se crea un nuevo protocolo para ese OtroViewController?

Comment: Si, creas los protocolos que quieras y haces un "delegado" del protocolo para cada uno que tenga que tratar

Comment: bien... ahora, al decirle que voy a llamar la vista para agregar items:                                                                          let vc = ViewController()      después...
vc. collectionControllerProtocol = self    después...                                                           cv.otroControllerprotocol = ''OtroViewController'' o Self??       y demás.... // algo que no le veo sentido que sea ''Self'' ya que no es el protocolo de esa Vista si no de la de OtroViewController.... o me equivoco? y lo demás seria igual  
 self.present(vc,animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: Entiendo que ViewController se va a comunicar por un protocolo con collectionControllerProtocol y con otro protocolo que es otroControllerprotocol, pues será del, que es ViewController que es quien va a recibir la información través del protocolo

Comment: hola @Spidvmp, saludos y disculpa por tanta pregunta,, en el segundo protocolo tengo problemas,  en el botón para abrir la vista para colocar items, le colóco  lo siguiente: hago la referencia de OtroViewController ..let otroViewController = OtroViewController( )..... y justo debajo en donde colocamos el delegado del primer protocolo pongo el delegado del segundo asi... vc. cv.otroControllerprotocol = otroViewController,  y listo con eso supuestamente ya me tiene que arrojar la info, pero me marca un error de desempaquetado en el protocolo ya revise pero no le veo problema alguno...

Comment: Abre una pregunta par no terminar con un chat en esta. Asi no mezclamos mas cosas

Comment: ya formule la pregunta haber si queda claro como lo coloque @Spidvmp